# What kind of equipment rules for low bonus dice and low pool points game?

Tags: house-rules, indie-rpg, solar-system, the-shadow-of-yesterday

**Background**

I've played in and story guided several games of the Shadow of Yesterday and Solar system, but in none of those we have used any formal equipment rules. Equipment has mostly made some actions viable and superior equipment may have given a bonus die now and then.

**Motivation**

I am houseruling Solar system into a credible dungeoncrawling game and would like to have some standard rules for magic items. I will probably handle mundane items as above, with no specific mechanics, but it is much harder to eyeball how, say, +2 mace would work without specific rules for magic items. Masterwork items and exotic materials might also get similar treatment.

**Existing solutions**

[TSoY](http://tsoy.crngames.com/Resolution#Weapons_and_armor) and Menneisyyden varjot both have items increase or decrease damage done in bringing down the pain / syvennetty selkkaus.

In [Solar system](http://solarwiki.janus-design.it/en/book/chapter-eight-secrets-and-crunch) the equipment rating adds to a successful check result or reduces opponent check result. Solar system also discusses handling items as effects.

In [World of Near](http://solarwiki.janus-design.it/en/book/front-matter) allows replacing check result with the equipment rating. There's also overflow dice and imbuements and other such complications.

**Questions**

Which of these equipment rules, or which alternate equipment crunch, would work in a low bonus dice and very low resource pool environment? Would using these different rule sets in parallel cause problems, and if yes, what kind of problems?

Answer (score 2):

**My current solution**

Mundane equipment may be simple fictional stuff which allows you to attempt things and maybe get a bonus die every now and then. A torch allows you to see in dark, for example.

Mundane equipment may also be an effect, in which case it is created with a relevant check (often barter) and expending wealth according to the value of the item; upkeep is also in money, not pool points. The effect is [fragile and limited](http://solarwiki.janus-design.it/en/book/front-matter). Effect value at zero might mean the item is destroyed or simply that it acts as per the paragraph above. Effect buys reliability, in other words.

Magical equipment works as per the World of Near rules.